# how clear New object created on javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, domparser

when we define a new object in javascript and it's repeat in a setinterval we see memory usage increase. what we can do for empty memory from that new object and decrease our memory usage

```
    setinterval(function(){
mydoc = new DOMParser();
/* do some thing with mydoc */
},1000);
```

what is wrong in my code , and how i can empty memory from that variable ?

Comment: @MOB: What exactly is that "do some thing"? It is relevant for the answer.

Comment: a string become a dom object and some sibling and getting data from that ... and result send to another function

Comment: What result? Does that other function store some of the XML nodes or so?

Comment: result sent to a function for send to a php file for update mysql data base

Comment: Unlikely, you cannot send XML nodes but have to serialize them; that should not leak. It would be easier to answer if you could post the code of this, you might [edit] your question.

Comment: @Bergi can i email that for you ?

Comment: No, please post the relevant parts of it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setinterval(function(){
  var mydoc = new DOMParser(); /create a variable/
  /* do some thing with mydoc */
  mydoc = null; //manually empty mydoc!
},1000);
```

Comment: What difference would it make? `mydoc` goes out of scope at the end of the function anyway.

Comment: var mydoc limits within the anonymous function. and "mydoc=null" just do set!

Comment: But why, when it is unncessary?

Answer (score 1):

It may make sense to cache the object and reuse it.

Something similar to:

```
var mydoc = new DOMParser();
setinterval(function(){
    /* do some thing with mydoc */
},1000);
```

If you need to use new objects then calling `delete` on the reference or simply setting it to `null` before new assignment might improve things in some browsers.

Comment: cant do that ... dom should define in setinterval !

Comment: Any reason for that? You are using a global variable anyway (if your code is accurate). Note that defining the object can happen once but the parse calls can still be in setInterval, I have tested this and the variable won't be deleted due to scope or so for example. http://jsbin.com/darox/1/edit?js,console 
You may try setting it to null or deleting it.

Comment: in question i comment the resone